# What should I do to solve this issues in stretch with overflow property of parameter in jasper report generation?

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports

I was doing some report generation using jasper report in Jasper Studio plugin of Eclipse Spring Tool Suite and I am stuck at stretch with overflow property of a parameter in J Report (since my data is coming dynamically in that parameter), where 
if the data size is increased then it should increase the band (parameter) size and dynamically align rest of the bands as it is, only their position will be moved (in my case downwards).

Here is my proper designed template image link. 
[In this image, you can see my template and the dynamic field with stretch property is DIRBFSInfo parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gudEM.png)

As shown in the img, my temp design shuld look like this and it is showing proper o/p in java preview like I have shown in the 2nd img.
[Report template proper design even if data stretch in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff9Zw.png)

but, when I preview for HTML o/p, it breaks all the design and things get ugly.
Here is the 3rd image of html preview.
[Messed up Html o/p of jasper report template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ5fL.png)

I don't know what i have to do to make that messy Html O/P, look like neat Java o/p, even if data is overflown and parameter get stretched.

Comment: We need to see some sample JRXML in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, I will add my jrxml file screen shots.